# mod_rewrite this - multiple conditions or can I just pass all vars over together?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Due to a reverse proxy setup I'm having to pass an extra query var which the proxy can't using mod_rewrite. The proxy is at /search however I'm using /find on all pages as a mod_rewrite to /search to pas the query var s=gsacollection.

See example:

```
# Direct link to search which passes collection var
# eg http://www.domain.com/find
RewriteRule ^find$ /search?s=gsacollection [NC]

#Rewrite all query vars
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^find(.*)$ /search?%1 [NC,L]
```

I'm trying to capture multiple variables for mod_rewrite that are being sent. The issue is I don't always know which ones are being sent over. This is an attempt to blanket capture them. Suggestions?

**I want to pass all the query strings after /find? to /search?**

EG here are some sample URIs coming in:

```
find?q=test&sort=date:D:L:d1&num=10&s=gsacollection&l=en&start=10

find?q=tfsa&sort=date:D:L:d1&num=10&s=gsacollection&l=en&filter=0

find?q=tfsa&filter=0&num=10&s=gsacollection&l=en&sort=date%3AD%3AS%3Ad1
```

If a blanket *capture* won't work then I will have to look at setting up multiple RewriteCond rules, wondering if there's a way I can combine these in a way I can pass vars from each condition to build the rewrite rule (eg group)?

```
# Grab everything after /find and replace with /search if these query vars exist
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=(.*) [AND]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=(.*)
RewriteRule ^find(.*)$ /search$1
```

Comment: Looking into some of the rewrite flags, the QSA seems like it may work however it's not working for me.

` #Rewrite all query vars`
  `RewriteRule ^find(.*) /search?$1 [QSA] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code in your .htaccess file under $DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10

RewriteRule ^find/?$ search?s=gsacollection [QSA,L,NC]
```

Make sure you don't have any other conflicting mod_rewrite rule here. `QSA` flag will make sure to append all query parameters to merge with `s=gsacollection` parameter.